# how to change stacked bar chart color and hide y-axis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pygooglechart

I want to change that graph color and hide y-axis values but how can I do this. Please help me. Here is my code-

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(datas);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { 
                        calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" 
                       },
                       2]);
var options2 = {
        width: 555,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
        isStacked: true,
         vAxis: {
            baselineColor:'Black',
            textPosition: 'none',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            }
        }
      };
```

[image: Graph Take some default color in it but I want to change that color]

Answer (score 0):

Bar color change:

```
var options= {colors: ['red','green'],}
```

Hide Y Axis:

```
vAxis:{
     baselineColor: '#fff',
     gridlineColor: '#fff',
     textPosition: 'none'
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but color change code is absolutely perfect and working properly but hide y-axis is not working.

Comment: Can you set color to transparent?

Comment: yes, I tried to color: transparent also but this is also not working. I don't know why? problem is only y-axis text color otherwise it's working perfectly but I don't understand how to hind y-axis text. I almost try every possible way to do this.